# How to zoom in leaflet fuse search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I am using leaflet and leaflet fuse search to search the line drawn in a map.
Currently my code :

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([1.3096622448984000, 103.7689017333800], 12);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=fhi', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(map);
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();

    var options = {
            position: 'topleft',
            title: 'Search',
            placeholder: 'enter link id ',
            maxResultLength: 15,
            threshold: 0.5,
            showInvisibleFeatures: true,
            showResultFct: function(feature, container) {
                props = feature.properties;
                var name = L.DomUtil.create('b', null, container);
                name.innerHTML = props.id;

                container.appendChild(L.DomUtil.create('br', null, container));

                var cat = props.id
                    info = '' + cat + ', ' + 'th link';
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(info));
            }
        };

    var searchCtrl = L.control.fuseSearch(options);

    searchCtrl.addTo(map);
searchCtrl.indexFeatures(zones.features, ['id']);
info.addTo(map);
```

So now when I search I am able to display a popup.But additionally I want to zoom into the map when I do the search is it possible?Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy here the answer I made for [How to zoom and change color in leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785434/how-to-zoom-and-change-color-in-leaflet) which is the same :

I guess we have to modify the createResultItem function :

https://github.com/naomap/leaflet-fusesearch/blob/master/src/leaflet.fusesearch.js#L286

It seems the function allows only openPoup / panAndpopup as event, it would be usefull to add other events or pass personnal function at this step